# Deployment of public groups and the associated users

Tags: deployment, public-group

Do i have to manually add the assigned users to a public group, after a group is migrated using the 'ant migration tool'?

If i retrieve a public group using the below package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Asia_Fun_Community</members>
        <name>Group</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

I get a metadata that doesnt have any info about the 'assigned users' to the above grp. So when i deploy the group in the target sandbox, it doesn't have any assigned users?

Is this a standard approach to do a manual step of adding the 'assigned users' to the deployed/migrated group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can migrate the members of your group using dataloader or workbench. The object's data that you are going to be working with is [GroupMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm). You will export the Group Members from the source org and import that data into the target org.

You may need to correct any User ID values in the resulting CSV that don't exist in your target org, but assuming that your sandbox is relatively new - it's probably got the same user ids in both environments.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004831&type=1

Comment: pls help me understand, that is for the data of the members. But why is a public groups metadata, doesn't have the metadata information of the group members? Something like, this group - SomeGrp, have the following group members assigned in the group's metadata

Comment: group membership isn't metadata, it's actual data in the org

Comment: Well, the name of the data can be a metadata. After moving the groupmember (using the tools), to the target org, The public group will know(will have the metadata information) about the assigned groups.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an older post, but I am not sure this is entirely correct.
The Group object has information about Public Groups and Queues, you can data load it as well, or, you can use the Metadata API to create.  The Group Members is also data but not exposed to the Metadata API.  So I believe that both Group/Queue and Group Members are both data in the Org, not a mix of Metadata and Data.